# Multiple functions in Flask API

Tags: python, api, flask, heroku

Hello everyone i made a flask api and deployed it to Heroku which returns me some url and its working perfectly fine but now i want to define another function in it and i defined it the way i thought it was right but its not working it says bad request when i try to call the new function that i defined. Here is the code:-

```
import flask
from flask import request
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def downloader():
    url = request.args['url']
    mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone 6/7/8" }
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    op.add_argument("--headless")
    op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),chrome_options=op)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(29)
    driver.refresh()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 29).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//video[@class="video-stream html5-main-video"]')))
    # element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//video[@class="video-stream html5-main-video"]')
    video_source = element.get_attribute('src')
    return video_source
@app.route('/another_route', methods=['GET'])

def details():
    stats = request.args['stats']
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    op.add_argument("--headless")
    op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),chrome_options=op)
    driver.get(stats)
    return "stats"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

now someone please tell me how to define the second function and what to add in the url that i got from heroku.
Before making the another function i simply use this url :-
https://example.herokuapp.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1GIv5UumvM&ab_channel=TanmayBhat
and now when i have another function i try to use it like this :- https://example.herokuapp.com/another_route/?stats=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1GIv5UumvM&ab_channel=TanmayBhat

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Are you aware that you've misspelled `another_route` in your example link?

Comment: you know the answer to my problem?

Comment: We only know what you tell us. Based on your original question, the typo looked like an issue. What do your server-side logs show (check with `heroku logs`)? Again, please read [ask].